# The application of The Argument Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: !This question is from Shaum's Outlines for Complex Variables:]

This question was asked under the topic of "The Argument Theorem", which looks like this:

[image: !Here is the mentioned theorem:]

I do not know how to get rid of $z$ on the numerator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: Are you interested in a solution which does *not* use that theorem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think by Residue Theorem I can eventually find the residues of the function zf'(z)/f(z) by determining the roots of f(z), but that would be a long work, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$f(z)=(z-2)^2\left((z+1)^2+4\right)$ then $f(z)$ has the zero $z=2$ of order $2$ and two simple poles at $z=-1\pm2i$. Also $g(z)=z$

Comment: I think you meant "two more zeros of order 1 at z= -1 + 2i and z= -1 - 2i " .

Comment: Yes. Two more zeros of order 1!

Comment: Sir, so what you just wrote, zeros of $f(z)$, and you denoted $g(z)= z$. From this how could we solve that integral? Sir please elaborate your method and is there is any other way too?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Please see the Spiegel Murray's book, Complex Variables with an introduction to CONFORMAL MAPPING and its applications, Schaum's Outline series (1993), page 137, problem 90. This answer is just for someone who didn't read the book well.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi For another method see above comments, one has a method as he said!